# MaterializeCSS NavBar and SideNav

Tags: css, materialize

I'm creating a sb admin 2 like page where it has 2 navigations that looks like this:

[image]

And what I've done so far is this:

[image]

As you can see, the side navigation extends at the top bar. My code so far is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Import materialize.css-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>

    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  </head>

  <body>

<div class="navbar-fixed">

<!-- Dropdown Structure -->
<ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
  <li><a href="#!">User Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">Settings</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href="#!">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
<nav class="light-blue lighten-1" role="navigation">
  <div class="nav-wrapper container">
    <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Point of Sale</a>
    <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
      <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
      <li><a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown1">Profile<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>


</div>

<ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav fixed">
  <li><a href="#!">First Sidebar Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">Second Sidebar Link</a></li>
</ul>

    <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      (function($){
        $(function(){

          $('.button-collapse').sideNav();

        }); // end of document ready
      })(jQuery); // end of jQuery name space
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What I am trying to achieve is this:

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: this also help https://stackoverflow.com/a/38125027/2130573

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[As the Side Nav documentations says:](http://materializecss.com/side-nav.html)

You have to offset your content by the width of the side menu.
so do like this

```
<style type="text/css">
.wrapper {
    padding-left: 300px;
}
</style>
```

and wrap your code in wrapper div

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="">
        <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
        <ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
            <li><a href="#!">User Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">Settings</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#!">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>

        <nav class="light-blue lighten-1" role="navigation">
            <div class="nav-wrapper container">
                <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Point of Sale</a>
                <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                    <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
                    <li><a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown1">Profile<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>

</div>

<ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav fixed">
    <li><a href="#!">First Sidebar Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">Second Sidebar Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @FewFlyBy yes, you can do, but you have to write a custom css for that layout...
1. Move out navbar from wrapper tag
2. increase z-index for navbar
3. and move slide nav from top as navbar height

hope this helps you..

Answer (score 5):

here is my fix to avoid over lap with the top navbar, and to hide on small to med screens

add:

```
<ul class="sidenav sidenav-fixed invesible-top" id="mobile-nav">
```

also optional to make it show on top again on small screens:

```
<li class="hide-on-large-only">
```

style:

```
  @media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
  .invesible-top {
    top: 65px;
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I like your solution, however the overlay continues all the way to the top. I added .sidenav-overlay {top: 65px} to the css which sort of fixes it except that if there are 2 sidenavs (one as part of the main menu an the other as a filters menu) then both are affected.

Answer (score 3):

You should try:

```
<style type="text/css">
.side-nav{
    top: 65px;
    width: 250px;
}
</style>
```

and wrap your code in header and aside:

```
<header>
<div class="navbar-fixed">

<!-- Dropdown Structure -->
<ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
  <li><a href="#!">User Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">Settings</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href="#!">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="nav-wrapper">
<nav class="light-blue lighten-1" role="navigation">
  <div class="nav-wrapper container">
    <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Point of Sale</a>
    <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
      <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
      <li><a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown1">Profile<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
</header>

<aside>
<ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav fixed">
  <li><a href="#!">First Sidebar Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">Second Sidebar Link</a></li>
</ul>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometime I ran into some problem when Nav was overflowing beyond the width of its wrapper (in my case, header tag) so I use this instead of what MaterializeCSS recommends:

Note: In sass though.

```
header, main, footer {
    margin-left: 300px;

    nav {
        left: 300px;
        right: 0;
        width: auto;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {
        margin-left: 0;

        nav {
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            width: auto;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MaterializeCSS recomends his own modification for this:

```
header, main, footer {
  padding-left: 300px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {
  header, main, footer {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}
```

Reference [here](https://materializecss.com/sidenav.html#variations).

Comment: Down vote due to the reference link going to a 404 page and this not seeming to have anything to do with the question asked.